# Issue in f-string inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this baaasic script of f-string inside a function, i want to know why there is no returned result when i run it :

```
def show_me_ip(ip, mask):  
     return f"IP: {ip}, mask: {mask}"  
show_me_ip('10.1.1.1', 24)
```

Thank you all for your supports.

Comment: You called a function, got a returned value, and *did absolutely nothing with it*.  You'd have to write something like `print(show_me_ip(...))` to have any visible output.

Comment: Works fine on my machine. Try `print(show_me_ip('10.1.1.1', 24))`

Comment: Thank you guys for your support, i forgot the print ^^' ! it works now.

Comment: Or you could change the `return` clause by `print` inside the function and call it just like `show_me_ip('10.1.1.1', 24) `

Answer (score 1):

```py
def show_me_ip(ip, mask):  
     return f"IP: {ip}, mask: {mask}"  
print(show_me_ip('10.1.1.1', 24))
```